# Auto complete For Metro TextBox

Tags: c#

I'm using Metro framework to build a windows Form Application.
There need a Auto Complete Text Box To Show Suggestion Name.
I've done this before lots of count but in metro dll. It does not support .net Auto complete Library Any help Please ???

```
 private void NameAutoComplete()
    {
        aManager = new InventoryManager();
       // aMember = new Member();

        string[] memberNameFromJoinedDatabase = aManager.GetMemberNameWithDesignamtion(cmbOrgMetroComboBox.ValueMember,Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartmentMetroComboBox.ValueMember)).Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Name, x.MemberDesignation.Name)).ToArray();


        txtNameMetroTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txtNameMetroTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        autoComplete.AddRange(memberNameFromJoinedDatabase);
        txtNameMetroTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
    }
```

My Load And Text Field 
it's not working for

```
txtNameMetroTextBox.AutoCompleteMode
                     txtNameMetroTextBox.AutoCompleteSource
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? does it fail to compile? with which error? Does it throw an exception at run time? which one? Does it just not perform as you expected?

Comment: also what class of object is `txtNameMetroTextBox`?

Comment: It's not taking txtNameMetroTextBox.AutoCompleteMode as ok txtNameMetroTextBox is from MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextbox and can't resolve symbol --AutoCompleteMode-- @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2455494/stewart-r